# Sharepoint Survey List

Tags: list-view, survey, survey-list

For the Survey requirement, we are planning to use the Survey List Template of the SharePoint.
The environment is SharePoint online

But we are not able to achieve the following points:
1.  Group by of Ticket Number in all the default views.
2.  Adding of the columns in the View.

Request you to provide any guidance if any one knows how to execute the above two points.

Comment: You need to manually create the views in SharePoint Designer.

Comment: as pointed out, you have to create custom view. here is little help http://burnignorance.com/sharepoint-tips-and-hacks/create-a-custom-view-for-survey-list/

Answer (score 2):

create a custom view with filter, with filter you can group all the ticket numbers or else you can create a group in list list settings-->views--> create or modify the view and you sort filter as you required . [image]